# Is emulation and/or virtualization faster when the host and guest systems are more similar?

Tags: computer-architecture, operating-systems

Is emulation and/ or virtualization performance faster when the guest and host OS are similar? If yes, how big, relatively speaking, is the difference? And whether the answer is yes or no, *why is it so*?

For example:

**Same architecture**

Will a x86 Windows host emulate and/or virtualize an x86 Android guest faster than it will an ARM Android guest?

**Similar OS**

*In the following two examples, please ignore the fact that Debian is arguably more resource efficient than Windows, and simply focus on **relative** emulation/virtualization performance.*

Will a Windows 10 host emulate/virtualize a Windows 7 guest faster than it will a Debian guest? (All are x86.)

**Remotely similar OS**

Will an OS X host emulate/virtualize a Debian guest faster than it will a Windows guest? (All are x86.) (Since OS X and Debian are both UNIX or UNIX-like.)

I would appreciate if any answers used many layman terms and analogies to explain in a way that people who are not computer scientists could understand it.

Comment: When you talk about emulation, its the same, because essentially, in emulation you simulate everything. Virtualization on the other hand is a different story.

Comment: @Haris Actually, I wasn't aware until now that there was a difference. I will edit the question. I want to know about both.

Comment: I don't think this is a computer *science* question as it asks for performance characteristics of real-world artifacts that depend on implementation details. (Why don't you just run experiments?) Community votes, please: is this offtopic?

Comment: @Raphael Can you suggest where on SE this could be posted? Also, as for why I don't just run experiments: Maybe I don't have the proper hardware, maybe I don't own copies of Windows, maybe I don't have access to a Mac, maybe I don't have a proper internet connection to download all these OS'es, etc, etc, etc. I live in rural India, by the way. Also, an answer to a question like this can tell us _why_ it is so, while experiments may not. Also, other people who have the same question may be interested in reading this, rather than spending hours making experiments.

Comment: My point is: there probably is no answer beyond experiments. Technical details are likely to overwhelm all principled ideas. That's my intuition, anyway. As for suitable SE sites: I don't know, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, virtualization on the same architecture will be a lot faster, if the architecture has built-in support for virtualization (as modern x86 processors do).  With hardware support for virtualization, most code will run at full speed.

If you want to "virtualize" onto a different architecture, then under the hood the VM will probably end up doing emulation.  Emulation is much slower.

To understand why, I suggest you do some more background reading about how virtualization and emulation work.  You could start with Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware-assisted_virtualization and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_virtualization and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulator.  If you'd like more details, you could check out an appropriate textbook (e.g., a good operating systems textbook).

---

The operating system most likely won't matter -- at least, there's no fundamental reason why it needs to make a difference.  (It might make a difference for engineering reasons rather than scientific reasons, e.g., due to a 32-bit vs 64-bit OS, or due to lack of support for features used by the VM software.)  The only way to know for sure is to do some experiments: measure performance on workloads you care about.

Comment: What do you mean by "virtualize onto a different host"?

Comment: @Fiksdal, oops, that didn't make any sense, did it?  Edited.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: What about the part about similar vs dissimilar operating systems?

Comment: @Fiksdal, see edited answer.  If you need more detail about that, you'll probably need to do experiments yourself (and it gets into material that's off-topic for this site and is likely to be specific to particular VM software; questions that are specific to particular software tools/packages are off-topic here).